# Replace an old item with a new item in DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-dynamodb

I'm using https://godoc.org/github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/service/dynamodb#DynamoDB.PutItemRequest

My function looks like:

```
  func (h dynamoHandler) save(selection DeliveryDate) (err error) {
      av, err := dynamodbattribute.MarshalMap(selection)
      if err != nil {
          log.WithError(err).Error("failed to marshal selection")
          return
      }

      req := h.db.PutItemRequest(&dynamodb.PutItemInput{
          TableName: aws.String(h.Table),
          Item:      av,
      })
      _, err = req.Send()

      if err != nil {
          log.WithField("table", h.Table).WithError(err).Error("putting dynamodb")
          return
      }
      return
  }
```

I was under the assumption that since the partition key "wfr5a" is the same, the newer "chosen#2019-05-19T13:42:54+08:00" (a composite and sort key) should have replaced the row.

```
"OrderID (S)","StatusDate (S)","LastUpdated (S)"
"wfr5a","chosen#2019-05-19T13:42:54+08:00","2019-05-19T13:49:34+08:00"
"wfr5a","proposal#2019-05-19T13:42:54+08:00","2019-05-19T13:42:58+08:00"
```

Though as you can see, it created a new item. What am I missing to so that it just replaces the record, i.e. has only one unique row for "wfr5a"

Answer (score 1):

when you have composite primary key(partition key + sort key) the combination of the two fields are unique and not the partition key.

Comment: it comes down to your design. if you expect to have only one value per partition key, it doesn't make sense to have a sort key and removing the sort key will fix your issue. But if you want to have a history of status changes then you need to have OrderID and Status(without the timestamp) as your composite primary key and mange lates status using a method similar to [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-sort-keys.html)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you need to do is remove the sort key from the schema. That way, each item will be uniquely identified by partition key alone.

There is no API available to replace all items that have a partition key so to implement the behavior you are describing you would have to do a query-delete-put transaction to actually replace the old item with the new unless you change the schema.