# Email as the primary key for customer orders in DynamoDB?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have a order I want to store in DynamoDB, with the following fields:

- **Order date:** 2019-03-27 02:09pm
- **First Name:**   John
- **Last Name:**    Doe
- **Email:**    john@example.com
- **Phone:**    555-11434
- **Address:**  13 Lorong K Changi, Sunny Shores
- **City:** Singapore
- **Zip:**  654321
- **Country:**  Singapore
- **Status:** new, confirmed, delivered

(There is no unique order identifier decreed)

At first I combined First&Last name "John Doe" as the partition key and put order date as the sort key. That worked quite well until:

I figured I can't query the partition key (name of customer). I want to be able to look up customer orders, by customer!

Secondly URLs addressing the order would look like: `https://example.com/2019-03-27/John%20Doe...` i.e. the space does cause some confusion. Is there a more efficient way to encode the name?

I am most keen on email address, but from researching that, it seems like email is a bad field to use.

The access patterns are pretty simple. Need a way to:

- Look up an order
- Search by customer (could be name, could be email)
- Query by order status

I tried making a composite key with order status and order date, but that has not gone well: [Replace an old item with a new item in DynamoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56208145/replace-an-old-item-with-a-new-item-in-dynamodb)

Comment: You should create an internal identifier (e.g. uuid) which you know will be unique and immutable

Answer (score 2):

Most people in this scenario generate a UUID for the user, and make that the partition key.

If you use an email address as the partition key, it means your user cannot ever change their email address, at least not without some creative coding on your part.

It might be valid to use an email address in your case, for example if a user can never change email address. In that case you should just be able to URL encode the email address on your client. However if you want to avoid that altogether, you could accept the parameter in a Base64 encoded format, and decode it before use with DynamoDB.

If you decide to generate UUIDs and make these your partition keys, you would probably then create GSIs with partition keys of email address and order state. You can use these GSIs to access your data quickly with your specified access patterns.

Comment: I find UUIDs are not URL friendly (too long!). But I guess having email in the URL is daft too. I think I will use a random id generator like https://godoc.org/github.com/tv42/zbase32#EncodeToString for the partition key.

Comment: If I'm going to use a UUID for the PK just to turn around have make an email-address GSI ...  why not simply have the email be the PK?  (this is with your "can't change email" acknowledged)